# Outlier elimination in a imblearn pipeline affecting both X and y

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, imblearn

I aim to integrate outlier elimination into a machine learning pipeline with a continuous dependent variable. The challenge is to keep `X` and `y` at the same length, thus I have eliminate outliers in both datasets.

As this task turned out to be difficult or impossible using `sklearn`, I switched to `imblearn` and `FunctionSampler`. Inspired by the documentation, I tried the following code:

```py
from imblearn import FunctionSampler
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def outlier_rejection(X, y):
    model = IsolationForest(max_samples=100, contamination=0.4, random_state=rng)
    model.fit(X)
    y_pred = model.predict(X)
    
    return X[y_pred == 1], y[y_pred == 1]

pipe = make_pipeline(
    FunctionSampler(func = outlier_rejection),
    LinearRegression()
)

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train) # y_train is a continuous variable!
```

However, when I tried to fit the pipeline I got the error

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

which I think is because my dependent variable is continuous.

I suspect that `imblearn` is only compatible with nominal data. Is that true? If yes, is there another approach to solve my problem (e.g. with classic `sklearn` pipeline)? If not, where did I make a mistake in the code above?